# FFMPEG Encryption of Live Streams

Tags: ssl, encryption, ffmpeg

I am working on ffmpeg live streaming, where in i need to encrypt Live Streams. I am trying to figure out the same. I worked with AES, but it works only on a stored file. Can I use https or rtmpe etc by using private keys, SSL certificates etc?  Anybody who is working on the same, kindly share your thoughts.

Eg : I am streaming my live cam feed using

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

I want to take stream1 as Input and Encrypt it continuously. And at the other end I want to decrypt and Play.

Comment: Hi Brad. I tried to use a self signed SSL using ffmpeg. But nothing is working. Any pointers or links will be helpful.Or do i need to rebuild ffmpeg to support this?

Comment: What I'm getting at is the encryption shouldn't have anything to do with FFmpeg.  Send it over HTTPS, an SSL tunnel, anything.

Comment: Hi Brad.. So far I am using this command  "ffmpeg -i input tls://localhost:8090?listen&cert=server.crt&key=server.key". I generated self signed certificate and key. But I am not getting anything, I mean it doesnt stream. Am I doing it right?? Or any additional settings I need to do. Thank You..

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: Looking into this myself but from within a program. There should be a gstreamer plugin that handles encryption/decryption. There's certainly one that handles transmission/receiving so I'm using that approach. You might want to look at the ICE plugin for gstreamer.